# Grails remoteLink

Tags: ajax, grails, prototypejs

I'm trying to make a call to the server with Ajax using Grails remoteLink. The code is the following:

```
<g:remoteLink controller="event" action="recommend" id="1" onSuccess="recommend(e)" params="[artist:searchedArtist]">
   Recommend
</g:remoteLink>
```

The controller is:

```
 def recommend = {  
                .
                .
                .
   def jsonList = [artist: "${params.artist}",
           location: [
                lat:"53.872715",
                lng:"-1.372895"]
           ]

   render jsonList as JSON
}
```

and the javascript function is:

```
function recommend(response){
   var recommendedResults = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');

   var point = new google.maps.LatLng(${recommendedResults.location.lat}, ${recommendedResults.location.lng});
   var myMarkerOptions = {
         position: point, 
         map: map
       };
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOptions);    
}
```

My problem is that the recommend() javascript function is never being called.
Any thoughts? Thanks very much.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that the line:

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(${recommendedResults.location.lat}, ${recommendedResults.location.lng});
```

was not right. So just for debugging purposes, I tried with the "recommend()" javascript function like this:

```
function recommend(response){
    alert.window("Foo");

  }
```

and still doesn't work. The alert never pops up.

The code fragment of the remoteLink which appears in the html source is:

```
<a href="/Ontourtest/event/recommend/1?artist=deftones" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/Ontourtest/event/recommend/1',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true,onSuccess:function(e){recommend(e)},parameters:'artist=deftones'});return false;">Recommend</a>
```

Comment: Can you show your result html for this code?

Comment: I just updated the result html for the remoteLink. Thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure the response is getting to the browser; using a tool like Firebug?

Comment: Never used Firebug. I will have a go with that and see the results.

Comment: I checked with Firebug and the response is getting to the browser. From the Firebug console I see that is a POST method and the response is the JSON object: {"artist":"deftones","location":{"lat":"53.872715","lng":"-1.372895"}}. Shouldn't the response be GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was not with the Ajax. It was a mistake in the Javascript function. I was calling `alert.window()` instead of `window.alert()`.
Thanks for the Firebug tip Gregg.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem completely,

Please change your code to :

`< g:remoteLink controller="event" action="recommend" id="1" onSuccess="recommend(data)" params="[artist:searchedArtist]">
   Recommend
</g:remoteLink>`

you must pass **data** in onSuccess and onFailure function grails only understand it.